# Trying to create a new field returns "General Error: 1030 Got error 1 from storage engine"

Tags: database, error-message, custom-field

I recently updated the site to 3.5.5, so not sure if this has anything to do with it. It's been a while since the last field we created, so can not say for sure if this is correlated. Database on this site is fairly large, but my host dashboard shows no issue with DB memory or storage.
[image: Full Error message]

Comment: Can't see I've seen that one before... any chance you're running on Azure?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/74840ac4-0c44-4904-87b3-a1a56f9217b4/error-mysql-1030-got-error-1-from-storage-engine?forum=azurecosmosdb

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-database-for-mysql-8211-can-t-restore-database-with-error/ba-p/368896

Or your database has run out of disk space? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591708/mysql-error-1030-got-error-1-from-storage-engine

Comment: No, not running on Azure and as far as I can tell, no issues with disk space. The site is hosted on a Dreamhost VPS. My DH control panel shows my MySQL ram is at 50% usage and I have unlimited disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my DB server and it fixed the issue. Sorry for the false alarm, but I've never seen something like that before. Should have tried the DB restart before.